# Using Navigator.popUntil and route without fixed name

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to use Navigator.popUntil with routes that do not have fixed names?

I have a route created the following way:

```
  final _key_homepage = new GlobalKey<HomePageState>();

    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>  new HomePage(key: _key_homepage, somevariable1: 'some value', somevariable2: 'some value 2'),
    ));
```

Now when I receive push notification on any screen and display popup message, one of the buttons should lead to the route listed above. The route was already created and must be 'poped' to. How to do it?

With named route, it can be done like this:

```
 new FlatButton(
    child: new Text('Go to homepage'),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/homepage'));  

     //how to do the same without ModalRoute.withName('/homepage')

    },
)
```

Both 'key' and context of desired route is available. However recreating the route again does not feel like a good solution, because original route creation includes some variables (somevariable1, somevariable2, etc).

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should add a setting when pushing your route; with a custom name

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: RouteSettings(name: "Foo"),
    builder: ...,
  ),
);
```

Then you can use `popUntil` as you'd do with named routes

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("Foo"))
```

Comment: Failed assertion: line 48 pos 15: 'builder != null': is not true.

Comment: @user9139407 you have to pass builder property to MaterialPageRoute(...)

Comment: This little detail "settings: RouteSettings(name: "Foo")," should be part of the official documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 38):

If you do not use named routes or we want to the navigator to First active, you can use

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst)
```

Comment: This is perfect, it shows the initial home page (if you have structured your app that way)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for