# Flutter popUntil throws Bad state: Future already completed

Tags: dart, flutter

I have screens A->B->C->D

In B, C, D screens there is a button that should take you to screen A **keeping its state** (thus pushNamedAndRemoveUntil isn't appropriate here).

I want to use popUntil, that's how I do it, based on docs:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(ScreenName.mainScreen));
```

I get an error:
Bad state: Future already completed

Here is my main:

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  final pages = {
    ScreenName.mainScreen: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MainScreen(), settings: settings),
  };

  var configureApp = AppConfig(
    appName: 'TaskerMate',
    flavorName: FLAVOR_NAME.PROD,
    child: AppModelProvider(
      model: AppModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: TMTheme().get(),
        home: SplashScreen(),
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          pages[settings.name](settings);
        },
        routes: {ScreenName.mainScreen: (context) => MainScreen()},
      ),
    ),
  );

  Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {
    print('${rec.level.name}: ${rec.time}: ${rec.message}');
  });

  runApp(configureApp);
}
```

ScreenName.mainScreen -> static final String mainScreen = '/main';

Comment: @codygray I don't see this as a duplicate. The other question is not trying to resolve an error, like this one.

Comment: @Dark The accepted answer here (posted by the asker, no less) is nothing more than a link to an answer on the other question. Hard to see how it is not a duplicate. The *presentation* or formulation of the question is not relevant; what matters is that they have the same answers. I'm certainly willing to reconsider, as I'm not a Dart or Flutter expert, but the fact that the two questions have the same answer is a *very* strong suggestion that the questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Took me ages to find the answer, but if anyone finds themselves stuck with this problem, [Rémi Rousselet's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51535958) is what solved it for me:

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(settings: RouteSettings(name: "Foo")),
);
```

Add settings to MaterialPageRoute with name, then call popUntil like so:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("Foo"))
```

Comment: All my routes are named, and I still get the error when I use popUntil. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16602