# How to use Navigator.popUntil Flutter

Tags: flutter

I m doing a Flutter app and I would like to go back from page 4 to page 1. 
I have an error really strange :

> Bad state : Future already completed

I created a simple project to reproduce this bug :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      onGenerateRoute: routes,
    );
  }
}

Route routes(RouteSettings settings) {
  if (settings.name == '/page1') {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return Page1();
      },
    );
  } else if (settings.name == '/page2') {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return Page2();
      },
    );
  } else if (settings.name == '/page3') {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return Page3();
      },
    );
  } else if (settings.name == '/page4') {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return Page4();
      },
    );
  } else {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return Page1();
      },
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Page 1'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go Page 2'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page2');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Page 2'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go Page 3'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page3');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Page 3'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go Page 4'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page4');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page4 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Page 4'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go Back Page 1'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/page1'));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is duplicate question. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661156/flutter-popuntil-throws-bad-state-future-already-completed?rq=1) and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16602).

Basically what is happening is - when you start your app, page1 opens because it goes into the last else and there is no name assigned to it, so when you do popuntil that page name, it doesn't find it at all.

Comment: how to pass parameters with route?

Answer (score 68):

Instead of:

```
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Page1(),
            ),
          );
```

use:

```
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: RouteSettings(name: "/Page1"),
              builder: (context) => Page1(),
            ),
          );
```

and then you can use :

```
Navigator.of(context)
              .popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/Page1"));
```

Comment: If I'm having multiple routes with the same name then to which one it will pop?
The latest in the stack or the Last in the stack?

Comment: the nearest one

Comment: how to pass parameters with this route?

Answer (score 2):

### For `page_transition` plugin

In case you are using named Routes and [this](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition) Package for transitions between pages (and arguments):

```
MaterialApp(
 onGenerateRoute: (settings) => {
   switch (settings.name) {
      case "/yourRoute":
        final value = settings.arguments as String?; // only if you pass arguments
        return PageTransition(
          settings: RouteSettings(
            name: "/yourRoute", //HERE is where you name your route for using popUntil
          ),
          child: YourPage(
            parameters: value ?? "null",
          ),
          type: PageTransitionType.fade,
        );

     case "/yourNextRoute":
          ...

     }
   }
),
```

Edit your main like this to enable calling and using pop with named routes. This would look like this:
`Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/yourRoute"))` or `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/yourRoute",arguments: "12345")`