# How to replace 2 Navigator.pop with one method?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

Say I use `Navigator.pop(context)` 2 times in a row to close the AlerDialog and close the page. Is it possible to replace these 2 methods with one function? If so, how?

```
ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text('Do not save'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }),
```

Comment: If you're using navigation with named routes, then you can use the **Navigator.popUntil** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525086/how-to-use-navigator-popuntil-flutter)

Comment: Ok, I'll try, thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `Navigator.popUntil`

Here's an example of using it to pop all the way to the first route:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push<void>(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
            );
          },
          child: const Text('Second Page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog<void>(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Dialog(
                  child: Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Back Home'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            );
          },
          child: const Text('Open Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How to sort items in listview