# Go back to previous page in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I have a flutter app that connects via bluetooth with a device by pressing on the device name from the list of paired devices. This is the coding :

```
final BluetoothDevice server;


 DataCollectionPage({required this.server});
...............................................................................

               child: ListView(
                 children: devices
                     .map((_device)=> BluetoothDeviceListEntry(
                   device: _device,
                   enabled: true,
                   onTap: (){
                     if (kDebugMode) {
                       print("item");
                     }
                     _startDataCollection(context, _device);
                   },
................................................................................
void _startDataCollection(BuildContext context, BluetoothDevice server){
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
   return DataCollectionPage(server: server);
 }));
}
```

Then once I navigate to the "**DataCollectionPage**" page, I perform some actions and data collection methods and at the end I will be in other page named **"DataCollectionTimer"**. In this page a timer will be displayed on the screen for few seconds then at the end of this timer a Dialog will show to give some message and then finally Once I press the button close on this dialog, I want to go back to DataCollectionPage. So If I try to use

```
MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => DataCollectionPage(),   ),
```

It will give an error because parameter 'server' is required which I obtained from the list of paired devices that was in a different class.
Is there a way to go back to DataCollectionPage from the current one without going all the way back to the page where the list of paired devices is there.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the server field optional and then use popUntil

```
final BluetoothDevice? server;

DataCollectionPage({this.server});
```

Comment: I tried to do that but its sending me to a black screen. 
Navigator.of(context)
                                .popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/DataCollectionPage"));

Comment: This is another thread where they explain how to use it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525086/how-to-use-navigator-popuntil-flutter)