# Flutter :- How manage the backstack like in Android "SingleTask"?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, back-stack

I am trying to manage the `backstack` in `Flutter` like in `Android` we manage it from **`launchMode`** *(eg. SingleTask,SingleTop , Standard etc..)* , For it i have tried the `Routes` in flutter, but did not get the success, please check the below code, which i have tried to achieve the `backstack`.

```
Widget makeRoute(
    {@required BuildContext context,
    @required String routeName,
    Object arguments}) {
  final Widget child =
      _buildRoute(context: context, routeName: routeName, arguments: arguments);
  return child;
}

Widget _buildRoute({
  @required BuildContext context,
  @required String routeName,
  Object arguments,
}) {
  switch (routeName) {
    case '/':
      return SplashScreen();

    case '/A':              //// NAME OF SCREEN IS A
      return A();

    case '/B':              //// NAME OF SCREEN IS B
      MyBean docs = arguments as MyBean;
      return B(dataToShow: docs);

    case '/C':              //// NAME OF SCREEN IS C
      MyBean docs = arguments as MyBean;
      return C(dataToShow: docs);

    case '/D':             //// NAME OF SCREEN IS D
      return D();


  }
}
```

I am jumping the screens from A->B->C->D are as follow, 
From A->B , I navigate it like below.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/B');
```

From B->C , I navigate it like below.

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/C', arguments: myList[index]);
```

And finally, From C->D , I navigate it like below.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/D');
```

As from the above code, I successfully navigated to the A------>D screens and also carrying data successfully.

But my main concern is that i want to navigate from the D->A or D->B screen using the backstack without opening another screen, So i have tried the below code but ***it is not working*** , please check the below code.

From D->A, I have tried like

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/A'));
```

And even tried in this manner like below.

```
 Navigator.of(context)
          .popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/A"));
```

I even this way to manage the flow like below

```
 SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/A'));

                    });
```

But both are not working properly
Please check my **`main()`** class

```
void main() {
  runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: '',
        theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
          primaryColor: ColorConst.PRIMARY_COLOR,
          accentColor: ColorConst.ACCENT_COLOR,
          primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,


          accentColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
        ),

          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => makeRoute(
                context: context,
                routeName: settings.name,
                arguments: settings.arguments,
              ),
              maintainState: true,
              fullscreenDialog: false,
            );
          }

      )
  );
}
```

And getting the following exception from above code like below.

```
═ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2330 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp **file:///Users/apple/Documents/BitBucket%20Projects/loyalityapp_android/lib/main.dart:10:7**
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[image: Getting execption while navigate from the D->A]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the **`MaterialPageRoute`** and referred this link to get the solution [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535621/using-navigator-popuntil-and-route-without-fixed-name/51535958#51535958)

From A->B->C->D screen navigation, I have used this approach

From A->B screen

```
 Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      settings: RouteSettings(name: "B"),
                      builder:  (context) => SCREEN_B(),
                    ),
                  );
```

And from B->C, I haved used this along with parameters like below

```
 Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                settings: RouteSettings(name: "C"),
                builder:  (context) => SCREEN_C(dataToShow:myList[index]),
              ),
            );
```

From C->D screen

```
 Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      settings: RouteSettings(name: "D"),
                      builder:  (context) => SCREEN_D(),
                    ),
                  );
```

And main logic is here navigations from D->A or D->B, from below liens of code

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("A"));  //YOU CAN USE "B" TO NAVIGATE
```

At the last one more thing which I need to add here is that when I want to perform any action like refresh activity and anything else from screen D->A
Then inside the A screen, we need to use **`then`** method  like below

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: RouteSettings(
                name: "B"),
            builder: (context) =>
                B(dataToShow: MYLIST[index]),
          ),
        ).then((value) {
          //// THIS METHOD IS ENVOKE WHEN SCREEN COME FROM D->A OR B->A, YOU CAN PERFROM CAN TASK HERE
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the following code to pop until the route "/A" using Navigator.popUntil method then you should have to set your opening screen with the help of **"initialRoute"** property in your MaterialApp Widget **instead of "home"** property.

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/A'));
```

> Because, here you are navigating to the route "A" with the help of "push navigator routes" and want to pop using "named routes"

Also, you can set it with "/" route in your routes property as Follow,

```
initialRoute : "A",
```

**OR**

```
routes:{
          "/": (context)=> A(),
}
```

Every thing other is fine in your code.

Comment: I have already define initial routes **SplashScreen** in my code, please check it once on top.

Comment: What i need to change inside the **MaterialApp** widget, please help me on it.